# How can I limit beautiful soup to extract information from one tab only?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have written the following code which gives me title, writer of different news from marketwatch.com. I want this code to limit to latest news tab only but it copies information from other part of website along with latest news. How can I limit to latest news only? I am a new learner so any help would be appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import csv

page = urllib.urlopen('https://www.marketwatch.com/newsviewer/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')

div = list(soup.find_all('div', class_= "nv-details"))

Newlist = []
heading = []

Data_11 = list(soup.find_all("div", class_ = "nv-text-cont"))
for element in Data_11:
    bcd = element.text.strip()
    bcd = bcd.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    print bcd
    heading.append((bcd))

Writerlist = []

for value in div:
    writerwala = value("span")
    if writerwala ==[]:
        writerwala = "No writer"
    elif value("p", class_ =  "abs")==[]:
        writerwala = "No writer"               
    else:
        writerwala = value("span")[0].text
    print writerwala    

    abc = value.find_all('span')
    if abc ==[]:
        print "source not found"
    elif len(abc)<2:
        print "Date", abc[0].text
    else:
        writer = abc[0].text
    Writerlist.append((writerwala))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find the first ol (ordered list) element and iterate over the contained li (list item) elements like this you can get the you want which is from the first ordered list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

page = urllib.urlopen('https://www.marketwatch.com/newsviewer/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')

# find the first ordered list
ol = soup.find('ol')
# get the list items
lis = ol.find_all('li')
heading = []
Writerlist = []
# for each list item
for li in lis:
    h = li.find('div', class_='nv-text-cont')
    bcd = h.text.strip()
    bcd = bcd.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    heading.append((bcd))
    print (bcd)

    value = li.find('div', class_='nv-details')
    writerwala = value("span")
    if writerwala ==[]:
        writerwala = "No writer"
    elif value("p", class_ =  "abs")==[]:
        writerwala = "No writer"               
    else:
        writerwala = value("span")[0].text
    print (writerwala)

    abc = value.find_all('span')
    if abc ==[]:
        print ("source not found")
    elif len(abc)<2:
        print ("Date", abc[0].text0)
    else:
        writer = abc[0].text
    Writerlist.append((writerwala))
```

Answer (score 1):

In this page there are other news that use the tag `div class=="nv-text-cont"`. You have to delimit more precisely the tags that you want to select. I modified this line of your code to delimit only the news with the tag `div class=="nv-text-cont"` that are into the tag `div id="mktwheadlines"`. I only modify this line:

```
div = list(soup.find('div', id="mktwheadlines").find_all('div', class_= "nv-details"))
```

With this I got 40 results, instead of 80 as with the original code. I don't Know if those are the relevant results for you, but the logic is that you have to be more specific delimiting which tags will be selected.

Comment: Javier Santos: Thank you, I understood what you meant. Even I got 40 results and 40 is the correct one. I wonder how can I have it scroll down and get more than 40 results.